# Why does a button trigger a form submit in HTML?

Tags: html

This is a behavior I didn't expect: if I click on the Submit button of a form, and it submits it, I understand it. But if there is a button that isn't set to perform anything, why does it submit the form too?

```html
Hi
<form>
  Enter something <input />
  <button>
    Click me
  </button>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You can try and click on Submit, and the page goes away, as it is submitting to itself (to the same URL). But if you click on the button that says "Click me", it submits too. Why is that?

Comment: my goodness, I never knew about this... so if we have 3 buttons, they all have to be set to `type="button"`. That's quite verbose. I guess it could have been defaulted to `type="button"`, but obviously inside of the form, it is defaulted to `type="submit"`